# How to run javascript scripts directly from netbeans (using rhino) ?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, rhino, netbeans-7.1

I am using netbeans 7.1, i have read this manual http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaScriptUsersGuide but i don't understand how to run javascript files in netbeans, i don't find any "Run" menu entry.

What is the right way to run a javascript script from netbeans using rhino engine ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I see what it says there on the wiki page from your link, but I don't think they support that, at least not in the standard ant-based java project. I poked around a bit and found a couple people with the same question, but no answer on the NB forums.